# Make bottomBar in compose android scaffold as transparent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, scaffold, jetpack-compose-accompanist

In Android Jetpack compose,
I have a root level ModalBottomSheetLayout.
In its content, I have a Scaffold. Scaffold content has a list of data shown.
In bottomBar I am showing a logo with some top & bottom padding inside a Column. I want that this bottomBar content should be transparent so that the list content behind it should be visible.
How can I achieve this ?

```
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = modifier.background(
        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                NaviPayColor.textWhite.copy(
                    alpha = 1f
                ), NaviPayColor.textWhite.copy(alpha = 0f)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This is my Column. I even tried making background colour as Color.Transparent. But it doesn't work. Can someone help